# Provide utility and gen power to thermostat

Tags: thermostat, generator

I have a smart thermostat installed that is getting 24v power direct from the heat pump control panel.  The T-stat is also controlling a boiler that kicks on when the HP can't keep up in the winter.

The boiler is on gen power but the HP is not.  I would like to provide gen power just to the thermostat so when the power (HP) goes out I can provide gen power to the T-stat and the boiler and still get heat.

I guess the ultimate would be to put the HP on gen power too but that is a much larger undertaking. I am thinking I need some type of relay but because I am dealing with two separate power sources I am not so sure.  Maybe a 24v transfer switch?  Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: Can you power the t-stat from a power supply that is supplied by utility/generator power?  (I honestly don't think it's worth trying to run the HP from the generator - much better to burn the fossil fuel in the boiler than in the bigger generator.)

Comment: Depends a bit on how old the boiler is, but I agree that using the heat energy directly should have fewer losses...  I agree that if you can do it, switching the thermostat to be powered from the boiler, or from a transformer on the switchable circuit, seems like the right fix if you're trying to use a single t'stat to control both. My own plan involves separate smart controls on each, currently just setting the boiler to kick in at a few degrees below where ai have the heat pump running as safety net.

Comment: This should be achievable.  Please add to your question exactly how your system is wired.   Does the boiler have its own 24V transformer?  Is that connected to the thermostat?  Do you have air conditioning?  Is anything connected to Rc?   Is W2 connected to the heat pump controller, and that in turn controlling the boiler?  Or is there somehow an independent signal loop for the boiler through the stat?  How?

Comment: Sideways alternatives: A battery-powered thermostat?   Or, can your HP controller be on generator but not the actual heat pump?  Usually the pump is on the other side of a contactor!   If the controller is inside the blower housing, you might end up uselessly running the fan on generator; can the generator cope with running the fan but not the pump?

Comment: Does your boiler run **on fuel**?  A lot of heat pump installations are done because fuel doesn't exist. In those cases, the "emergency heat" is **electric heat strips** and you're not going to power those with a generator.

Answer (score 3):

It would be normal for the boiler controls to also include a 24VAC transformer.

The solution with the least complexity is to change the thermostat power to the boiler, rather than switching it to and fro. If the boiler is powered (the thermostat cares not how) the thermostat is powered.

Alternatively, put a good ol' dumb thermostat on the boiler for power outages. Leave it set below the lowest setting you let your smart thermostat go to *except* when there it's a power outage, and it won't affect that.

*Ideally (but then it's more replacing things you already have some version of) you get a liquid-cooled generator and dump its waste heat into the boiler distribution piping. Co-generation! Likewise, if you power the heat-pump, dump generator waste heat (air-cooled can work with this) where the heat pump can use it.*

Comment: 2nd suggestion, total separation, might be best.  For the first one, I think for one stat to send W and W2 signals to two different pieces of equipment, they both need to be powered by the same transformer.   A separate transformer can power the stat via Rc (unless OP also has A/C, which would complicate things more) but that transformer can't signal W2.  Or alternately with multiple transformers, perhaps if their Common sides are bonded it would work?   Also need to make sure stat's W2 doesn't go to HP controller, and call for boiler signaled from there?

Answer (score 2):

That's fine, go ahead and do that.

Here's the thing.  That 24 volt pilot power we use for thermostats... that comes from a **transformer**.  The furnace types are commodities and are around $15 with a varity of package types, including that mount on a junction box cover or on a standard 1/2" (actually 7/8" hole) knockout.

It's very common in North America to have multiple pieces of equipment in HVAC systems.  One or more of those has a transformer built into it as a convenience.   It's *possible* to use 2 transformers... but most people just pick one transformer and use it to power the whole shebang.

That can be the transformer in any piece of equipment, or it can be a discrete/separate transformer that just sits on a junction box. Some doorbells even use the same 24 volts.

The terminals coming out of a transformer are called R and C.  (if someone wants to use both the furnace and A/C transformer, they are Rc and Rh respectively, and now you know why your furnace has 2 terminals for that).  Anyway, you simply bring R and C to every place that needs it.  (each unit and thermostat, though simple thermostats don't need C and some equipment doesn't need R).

- R is generally preferred to be **Red**.
- C is generally preferred to be **Cyan** or **Cerulean** (blue) but heat pumps may use blue for other things; don't mess with that and choose another color.  Though, surely C is already in your heat pump wiring since it must already get from the heat pump to the furnace.

If you want to rearrange things, just keep those straight.

I would expect a furnace to have its own transformer, for when the product is used without a partner heat pump.  Because it would need 24 volts for operating the gas valve and controls. Just make sure the transformer is big enough - the typical commodity transformer is 40 VA, which is plenty for a whole house. If it's much smaller than that, just swap in a 40 VA unit.

What you're proposing to do is *not weird*.  90% of American homes have a forced-air furnace *precisely to make A/C easy*, and they use the transformer that is part of the furnace to run the whole show.  So having the transformer at the furnace is actually the norm.   Needless to say these houses go over to generator easily.

Make sure you are using appropriate inlets and interlocks or transfer switch to safely inject your generator power. Honestly depending on the size of the generator, the easier path might actually be to install a $70 generator interlock on your main panel with a $50 inlet on the outside of your house... allowing you to power every circuit (not *all at the same time, obviously*) so you would have no trouble turning on the furnace and refrigerator breakers so only they get powered.  No extension cords needed at that point. Every hurricane season they find a few houses full of corpses; they had a generator and left a door "cracked open" to let the extension cord through, and that was the ingress for the carbon monoxide.    At this point in the United States, *the plain majority* of fatalities in hurricane events come from foolhardy generator use.

Comment: Won't problems arise with two independent transformers trying to run signal loops to W and W2 through the same Rh feed?  IE, the furnace and heat pump each need a closed signal path from R through W and back to *their own C*.  You might get lucky if you bond all the Cs together?   Or you might need to use relays so the thermostat can have its own signaling path for everything that is independent of each machine's logic board?

Comment: @jay613 I would discontinue use of the heat pump transformer entirely.

Comment: Ah, if it's external or modular that's the solution.  One transformer to power them all.   But if it's baked into the logic board hmmmm ...UnfortunatelyI don't get the sense OP is going to provide any new info.